# Django 2.1 recalling old slug url variables

Tags: python, django, listview, url

I am having some issues directing a url pattern through the following type of path: Listview --> Listview2 --> DetailView. I am running into trouble with my url patterns. Here is what I am working with:

```
app_name = 'ism'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
path('<slug:client_slug>/', views.CostCenterListView.as_view(), name='cost_center_list'),
path('<slug:client_slug>/<slug:cost_center_slug>/', views.cost_center_detail, name='cost_center_detail'),
]
```

The home page of this app is a list of all clients. Clicking on a client will populate a new page showing a list of that client's sub-clients (cost_center).

Here is part of my template {% url %} call to my final path listed above (/slug/slug/):

```
{% for cost_center in cost_centers %}
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'ism:cost_center_detail' cost_center.slug %}">{{ cost_center }}</a></li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Adding this along with its accompanying view causes an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /ism/cleint_slug/
```

Can you confirm that my issue has to deal with my {% url %} in my template not remembering the first slug in my url path? My error message seems to indicate that it's trying to find:

```
.../cost_center_slug
```

instead of:

```
.../client_slug/cost_center_slug/
```

My assumption is that django would magically remember the first part of my url pattern (ie client_slug), but that does not appear to be happening. Do I need to bring in more context variables in my view to allow for the calling of two url variables (also is url variable the right terminology? It doesn't sound right) in my template above?

Here is my full error message ('cffd' is a slug representing a cost-center):

```
Reverse for 'cost_center_detail' with arguments '('cffd',)' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: 
['ism/(?P<client_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<cost_center_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Here is my views.py. I was initially trying to work with a DetailView and its get_object method, but I couldn't get that to work in addition to the function based view I shown

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'ism/index.html'        
    context_object_name = 'client_list'     

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Client.objects.all()
        return queryset


class CostCenterListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'ism/costcenter_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'cost_centers'

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('client_slug')
        client = Client.objects.get(slug=slug)
        queryset = client.costcenter_set.all()
        return queryset


def cost_center_detail(request, client_slug, cost_center_slug):
    cost_center = get_object_or_404(CostCenter, slug=cost_center_slug)
    context = {'cost_center': cost_center}
    return render(request, 'ism/costcenter_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error message with full traceback please?

Comment: Your diagnosis is wrong, that's telling you the page you are on when you see the error. But you need to show the view and full error traceback.

Comment: You can add full traceback to understand your problem. What I am assuming, in your 2nd url you are calling slug directly. My suggestion will be add `path(someword/<slug:yourslug>/), and also do this for the third url.

Comment: Hey @DanielRoseman - I added my views in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got a wrong url. It should be either

```
{% url 'ism:cost_center_list' client_slug %}
```

or (you don't provide enough argument to construct `cost_center_detail` url)

```
{% url 'ism:cost_center_detail' client_slug cost_center.slug %}
```

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion is what I am thinking is the problem too. However, I am not sure how to get the client.slug as a context variable in my second ListView (CostCenterListView)...my queryset is client.costcenter_set.all(), and I need that in order to generate the list of cost_centers for that particular client, but I can't get the object client.slug with that queryset. Do I just need another get_object/get_context_data method in my the ListView?

Comment: From your views' code, I think you could do `cost_center.client.slug`. I might be wrong if you define something else, but it should be pretty close w/o seeing `models.py`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much!